# vagrant ssh is calling 22 instead of 2222? - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, vagrant

For years I've used `vagrant ssh` to get into my VirtualBox / Ubuntu 16.04 setup.  I recently had problems with the default setup and permissions, an issue discussed extensively online, so started using custom keys.  I've pasted the public key into /home/ubuntu/authorized_keys in my Ubuntu box VM and pointed my Vagrantfile to the private key at ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa.

The problem is that when I `vagrant ssh` I get the error:

`vagrant@127.0.0.1: Permission denied (publickey)`

I can connect with: `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222`  but I want to use `vagrant ssh` again.

During boot up:  `SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222` and I can connect to that with Webstorm and the "OpenSSH and authentication agent" config.

```
    § vagrant ssh-config
        Host pfbox
          HostName 127.0.0.1
          User vagrant
          Port 2222
```

If I `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1` I get the message `ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused`

Maybe `vagrant ssh` is calling port 22 instead of 2222?  Maybe something is wrong with my custom keys setup?  I'm lost after lots of research online.

I used `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521` to create the keys which is recommended by OpenSSH on their site. I've also tried this with rsa.

MBP Mojave, Vagrant 2.2.3 / VirtualBox 6.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `vagrant ssh` is replying with an authentication error, port is still listening on port 2222.

I would suggest checking if the default private key is still there and readable (for example default for VirtualBox provider is `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key`).

If so, check logging in verbose (`vagrant ssh -- -vv`).
Anyway if local ssh works then it means there's a valid pkey in your `~/.ssh/` folder, so (for example) `vagrant ssh -- -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa` should work.

Comment: You are right about about the port.  The verbose flag for `vagrant ssh` is a BIG help.  I've never seen that before and I've done a lot of research about this problem.

`vagrant ssh -- -i ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa` failed with permission denied but `ssh -- -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa` logged me in.  I created both a few days ago `ssh-keygen`.  When rsa didn't work I made ecdsa.  It didn't work either.  The Vagrant docs on custom keys are sparse and expect users to know what they are doing.  I'm just starting to figure this out.

Comment: I changed this vagrant file line back to the rsa key and now I can log in with only `vagrant ssh`.  
`pfbox.ssh.private_key_path = ["~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key", "~/.ssh/id_rsa"]`  This didn't work previously so I suspect that during all my failed attempts I put the public key where it was needed so now it works.  So I copied the public key into /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys and now the ecdsa key will let me log in with only `vagrant ssh`.  Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Fernando gave me the tools to find the answer.  Big thank you to him!  However, I've done a lot of research on this issue and I want to show here what is important for solving this common problem.  This isn't covered well in the docs or other sources.

1)  Verbose diagnostics is very helpful.  `vagrant ssh -- -vv`

2)  In my vagrantfile I have this line:

`pfbox.ssh.private_key_path = ["~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key", "~/.ssh/id_ecdsa"]`

I'm using the newer key format ecdsa custom keys but I've also tried rsa.

3)  In my synced folder at the root level on my host machine I have .ssh with two files inside.  I copy and past the public key info from ~/.ssh on my computer into the authorized_keys file in the .ssh directory in my synced folder.  `vagrant ssh` is checking that file for the public key.  To create the synced folder add this to your vagrant file:

`mybox.vm.synced_folder "mydir/", "/home/vagrant"`

This mirrors you host working directory into the guest Vagrant server.

After this setup Vagrant knows where the private and public keys are and can ssh into the box.

A key point I never saw referred about anywhere in Vagrant or related SO and other locations is that the private key must be on the host and the public key in the box.  That is probably well known from elsewhere but for us newbies it is new and critical info, of course.